# Multiroot Treelist with datasource queries

Tags: tree-list

We had a requirement that we need to show 3 template locations in a Tree List field. We found similar questions here - [Multi-root treelist with queries](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18736/multi-root-treelist-with-queries), and created a multi-root treelist by following the above question, but we are unable to find the exact Datasource query that we need to use. We need to show only the required template and hide all other templates.

We tried the following queries -

```
query:/sitecore/templates/User Defined/Page Templates|/sitecore/templates/User Defined/Item Templates


datasource=/sitecore/templates/Page Templates&IncludeItemsForDisplay=Template1,Template2,Template3&ExcludeTemplatesForSelection=Template Folder&IncludeTemplatesForDisplay=Template|datasource=/sitecore/templates/Item Templates&IncludeItemsForDisplay=Dmat document&ExcludeTemplatesForSelection=Template Folder&IncludeTemplatesForDisplay=Template
```

But didn't get the actual results. Can you please help us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to apply datasource query like this -

```
datasource=/sitecore/templates/Page Templates|/sitecore/templates/Item Templates&IncludeItemsForDisplay=Template1,Template2,Template3&ExcludeTemplatesForSelection=Template Folder&IncludeTemplatesForDisplay=Template
```

This will give you multi-root paths.